# Compact convex subset and hyperplanes

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $K$ is a compact and convex subset and $x^*$ a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose there exists  $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$\langle x^*, y\rangle> \sup_{x\in K}   \langle x, y\rangle$$

Since support function is positive homogeneous, does it mean we can rescale $y$ such that

$$\langle x^*, y'\rangle> \sup_{x\in K}   \langle x, y'\rangle$$

for $y'=\lambda y$,$\lambda>0$ and $\|y'\|\leq 1$?

Similarly, would it be true that

$$K=\{x': \langle x', y\rangle \leq \sup_{x\in K}   \langle x, y\rangle \ \text{ for all  } \ y\in \mathbb{R}^n \ \text{ with }\  \|y\|\leq 1\}$$

Comment: I edited the formula: you can use `\text` to include text in formulas. Also, `\| \|` works better for the norm than `|| ||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to both questions. Dividing both sides of the inequality 
$$\langle x^*, y\rangle> \sup_{x\in K}   \langle x, y\rangle$$
by $\|y\|$ yields 
$$\langle x^*, y'\rangle> \sup_{x\in K}   \langle x, y'\rangle$$
where $y' = y/\|y\|$ is a vector of unit norm.

It follows that your characterization of $K$ in terms of the inequalities over all $y$ with $\|y\|\le 1$ is correct. Moreover, it would be enough to consider $\|y\|=1$ here.